# Shift Cells left whle filtering in ms excel 2007

Tags: excel-2007

I have a table and i filtered data based on one specific criteria and i want to shift cells left after deleting one selected column data.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

hey simply use = sign in require left cell and put column position which you want to put e.g if you have data in B1 cell & u want to put the data in A1(left) then simply write =B1 in A1 cell
and drag down upto where you want the data